# How to change Timeline display to hour min,sec using storyjs-embed.js

Tags: jquery, timeline

i am using timeline for creating beautifully crafted timelines but i am unable to change the scale instead of date it should display hour,min and sec scale.

How i can do that any one can plz help me..is it possible to that.

Comment: you can refer this url ...http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Beautifully-Crafted-JS-Timeline-Library.html

Comment: Do you want to cover only one/few days in your timeline?

Comment: I want only 2 hour no date format...like 0 min to 120 min thats it and also i want only time scale no other things along with with out moving time scale...if u can help me in that i really appreciate for that

Comment: How about setting era to something like this:
        "era": [
            {
                "startDate":"2011,12,10",
                "endDate":"2011,12,11",
                "headline":"Headline Goes Here",
                "text":"<p>Body text goes here, some HTML is OK</p>",
                "tag":"This is Optional"
            }
        ]
According to:
https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS#json

Comment: yes i m already following same things..but things is that i want to show only 2 hour scale with out any moving scale.i don't want display any date ..that i m unable to do that if u help me in that

Comment: If timelinejs api doesn't support such configuration You have to write code that will wait for timeline to render and then change certain objects (eg. delete movement buttons)

Comment: can you plz tell me how to stop the movement of the scale?

Answer (score 0):

To stop movement of the scale you can remove navigation buttons:

```
$(".nav-previous").remove;
$(".nav-next").remove();
```

Make sure to call them after timeline is rendered.